# Draggable marker with Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: drag-and-drop, google-maps-markers, draggable, google-maps-sdk-ios

Has anybody figured out how to implement draggable markers with the new Google Maps SDK for iOS? The API does not provide it natively, yet. Feature request is already submitted.

If I could get a hold of the underlying view of the GMSMarker, I could intercept the Touch events. Anybody tried this?

Comment: yes, two and they are both correct. please accept one (robert weindl's is cool) so this can be crossed of the list :D

Answer (score 19):

As of today, You don't need to use external classes, just make your markers "draggable"

```m
GMSMarker *myMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] ...];
...
[myMarker setDraggable: YES];
// Use some kind of data to identify each marker, marker does not have 'tag' but 'userData' that is an 'id' type
[myMarker setUserData: markerId];
```

And implement the respective delegate

```m
@interface YourController: UIViewController<GMSMapViewDelegate> ...
```

Set your delegate

```m
GMSMapView *myMapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] ...];
...
myMapView.delegate = self;
```

Then you can handle each marker event, ie:

```m
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didEndDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker{
    if ([marker.userData isEqualtoString:@"xMark"])
        NSLog(@"marker dragged to location: %f,%f", marker.position.latitude, marker.position.longitude);
}
```

Comment: Are there any way to disable MapView scrolling animation, when you start to drag the marker?

Answer (score 3):

Hello I just implemented a drag and drop functionality for marker in the new GoogleMaps SDK for iOS. I published the code on github under the following link: 
https://github.com/rweindl/google-maps-sdk-ios-drag-drop

Comment: it is showing wrong lat, long after drop a pin :(, Please cross check.

Comment: it works flawlessly for me. must be somewhere in your code... you could start by showing us some

Comment: funny that I cant download the zip file :\

Comment: As of Google Maps SDK June 2013 1.3.1 Google has added a gesture recognizer that messes with Robert's draggable method.    '<GMSBlockingGestureRecognizer: 0x11de50f0; baseClass = UIGestureRecognizer; state = Possible; cancelsTouchesInView = NO; delaysTouchesEnded = NO;'

Comment: Hey Jenni thanks for this information I will check this and update the draggable method in the coming days.

Comment: With 1.3.1 the gesture recognizer does no longer receive sufficient (any) touch events. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @All: I just updated the https://github.com/rweindl/google-maps-sdk-ios-drag-drop project to bypass the new GMSBlockingGestureRecognizer and enable drag and drop functionality again.

Comment: @RobertWeindl Page not found. can you update the link please

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0**

Sweet!   All I had to do was add this variable to my marker.  Then when carefully select and hold the marker for a moment you can drag it around.

```
marker.isDraggable = true
```

I have not yet implemented the delegates to save my marker data but here's what it should look like.

```
extension MapVC : GMSMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView (_ mapView: GMSMapView, didEndDragging didEndDraggingMarker: GMSMarker) {

        print("Drag ended!")
        print("Update Marker data if stored somewhere.")

    }

}
```

Note:  For a while I was trying to un-animate the screen and marker from floating and animating UP after selected.  Now I see that it's a "feature" since your finger is in the way and you can't really see well if it doesn't move the screen during a drag.  (Duh!)

Answer (score 0):

Draggable markers have not yet been added to the SDK. Please [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Comment: Done so already. See: [http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4975](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4975)