# I have implemented google map. what I want to do is, make markers visible only after a specific zoom(suppose 12 or 16)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, xcode6, google-maps-markers

I have implemented google map.now I have plotted some markers on map.what I want to do is, make markers visible only after a specific zoom(suppose 12 or 16).markers would be invisible from zoom 0-12 or 0-16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this delegate and write marker hidden code in this method. It gets called on zooming.

position.zoom will give you zoom level; after comparing you can show marker.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position;
```

Comment: How can i compare the zoom level

Comment: position.zoom is float value just compare it with 16 if you want zoom level 16

Comment: I got what i wanted so far :)

Comment: yes...Can you suggest me how can i drag my current location marker.because that marker comes by default.I have checked everywhere.I did not called any such marker to show current location.
****camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latfloat longitude:longfloat zoom:17 bearing:30  viewingAngle:0];****

self.mapvw = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.subView.bounds camera:camera];
    [self.subView addSubview:self.mapvw];
    self.mapvw.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    self.mapvw.settings.indoorPicker = NO;
    self.mapvw.settings.compassButton=YES;
    self.mapvw.myLocationEnabled=YES;

Comment: i did not get your point what you want.you just want to drag marker to particular location?

Comment: try this i hope you have not got what you wanted till now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045687/draggable-marker-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios

Comment: I have not mentioned any marker to show my current location.I jusy have zoomed my location with camera position.But by Default ,agoogle marker is placed.

Comment: maybe you have enabled to show your current location.that will not be a marker

Comment: GMSPlacesClient  --cannot be found. i get this error.I saw that i have this missing in my framework

Comment: try to check path for your library and add path in linker header path in build settings

Comment: I found alternative way...no need of cocoapods or anything.Just called the webservice.But still a bug...like when i backspace and no text left,it crashes